# How to get values of grid in GXT?

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gxt

```
List<ColumnConfig<Vo, ?>> l = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig<Vo, ?>>();
    l.add(numColumn);
    l.add(subjectColumn);
    l.add(nameColumn);
    l.add(dateColumn);

    ColumnModel<Vo> cm = new ColumnModel<Vo>(l);
    Grid<Vo> grid = new Grid<Vo>(store, cm) {
        @Override
        protected void onAfterFirstAttach() {
            super.onAfterFirstAttach();
            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    loader.load();

                }
            });
        }
    };

    grid.addCellClickHandler(new CellClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onCellClick(CellClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            contentPanel.clear();
            contentPanel.add(readPanel(contentPanel));

        }
    });`
```

When I click on cell, I want to get the data in the cell corresponding.
The current state,
When you click on of the cell, switch to a different view of the structure.
And I succeeded to connect to the database.
However, I want to get the data of cell or row.
How to get values of grid in GXT?
(example Site:[http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:paginggrid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3apaginggrid))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GXT Grid works with data stores, more precisely it is a ListStore I think. So that, to get Values of the grid either use that store by grid.getStore(), and after that you basically have a collection of the objects in your grid (grid.getStore().getAll() return List), or you can use Grid's SelectionModel to deal with the grid selected item like this:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler<Vo>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<Vo> event) {
            if (grid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                // Do whatever you want
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the answer in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of a single cell you can try this inside the `cellClickHandler` :-

```
ListGridRecord record =  event.getRecord(); 
int colNum = event.getColNum();  
String fieldName=grid.getFieldName(colNum);
String cellValue=record.getAttribute(fieldName);
```

`cellValue` will have the desired value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I used paginggrid of GXT.(example Site:http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:paginggrid)

Comment: Pardon my knowledge of GXT, but how would paging grid be different?